# How to make AMAROK "see" my ipod 6Gen classic?

Tags: ipod, amarok

The problem: When I mount my ipod Classic, Amarok will not show it, there is no devices tab, too. The system WILL see the ipod, though, other apps - Clementine, Rhythmbox WILL see the ipod and read it and the database correctly. I use 11.10 Ubuntu, tried with live Kubuntu 11.10. 
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the PC, plugged the iPod and waited for a WHILE(more than 5 minutes), and the database of the the player was read. Amarok did it  comparatively  slower to other players, so be warned.